# Sorting and indexing 3D arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing

Let A and B be 3D arrays of the same size. I would like to sort each page of A and (quickly and efficiently, of course) permute B such that its new indices will correspond to the new indices of A. I.e. I want to make Bs entry permute in the same manner as As.

The naive approach is to do

```
  [sortedA,idx] = sort(A);
    newB=B(idx);
```

However, this does not work because A(idx) is not equal to sortedA. A(idx) instead makes all the pages copies of the first sorted page.

What is the solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shot #1 (Sorting along columns in each 3D page/slice)**

```
%// Get size of A
[m,n,r] = size(A)

%// Sort A along each column and get the corresponding sorting indices
[sortedA,idx] = sort(A)

%// Get the corresponding sorting indices for B and get the new B with them
idxB = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,idx,[0:n-1]*m),permute([0:r-1]*m*n,[1 3 2]))
newB = B(idxB)
```

**Shot #2 (Sorting for all elements in each 3D page/slice)**

```
%// Get size of A
[m,n,r] = size(A)

%// Reshape A into a 2D array and then sort it, and 
%// also get the corresponding sorting indices
[sortedA,idx] = sort(reshape(A,[],r)) 

%// Get corresponding sorting indices for B, index into B with it,
%// reshape it and have the desired re-arranged B
idxB = bsxfun(@plus,idx,[0:r-1]*m*n)
newB = reshape(B(idxB),size(B))
```

Comment: The second code is not working with, for example, A=randn(2,1,2).

Comment: @GregorianFunk Sorry that was a typo there, check it out now?

Comment: @GregorianFunk So, you were looking for `Shot #2 (Sorting for all elements in each 3D page/slice)` and not Shot #1 right? Please note that these two shots would yield different results.

Comment: Basically I cared about shot 2 because of the way my code works, but I am interested in the general answer too. I thought there might be an analogous way to do both because of the way the sort command works for 2D matrices.

Comment: @GregorianFunk I am not sure what you mean by *general answer* here, can you explain?

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that it seemed to me that if one could do the case where one is sorting columns on each page, this would also yield a solution for the case where you vectorize each page. So for me the more general case is where each page is not a vector, but a 2D matrix.

Comment: @GregorianFunk Hmm, well both these shots work for cases where a page is a 2D matrix or a vector. So, going by your definition of a *general case*,  both of these fit the bill. The difference between two shots is just that *how would like to sort elements in each page*.